SXA rendering HTML Snippet not loading data until CD is restarted
In our Sitecore SXA application v10.1.3, I have added the default rendering HTML Snippet (with the placeholder "body-top"), to the default partial design Metadata and assigned the datasource.
Published both the datasource item and the Metadata partial design, but the content is not loading on the site.
When I preview the page, the content loads as expected. So, I restarted CD and now the changes render fine.
I moved the changes to a higher environment and it is the same issue here. Republish & clearing cache from cache.aspx did not work.
Is it something with the Metadata partial design?
Is there a way to fix this without restarting the CD?
Thank you

Did you try republishing a page to check if that works (on that page)?

@Gatogordo That worked!!! I re-published a random page and now I see that content in all pages. Could you please help me understand the reason for this behavior. Thank you

I have seen behavior like this before with SXA. In most cases republishing a page helps.
The "why" question I can't answer exactly though. There is some caching in place that gets cleared with a (re)publish but I haven't been able to determine where and how yet.
Of course, it could be the ootb caching that can be set on pages and components as well.
